# How do I eliminate repeat code in nested imports?

Tags: python, dry

I'm trying to write DRY (don't repeat yourself) imports.

I have removed repeat code from WET (write everything twice) imports like this.

```
# example 1
from foo import foo_2
from foo import foo_3
```

Repeat code from example 1:

```
from foo import
```

The fixed (DRY) version of example 1:

```
from foo import (foo_2,
                 foo_3)
```

How do I fix WET imports that look like this?

```
# example 2
from foo import foo_2
from foo.foo_3 import foo_4
from foo.foo_3.foo_5 import foo_6
```

Repeat code from example 2:

```
from foo
from foo.foo_3
```

I would like example 2 to look like this (DRY, but not real code).

```
from foo import (foo_2, 
                .foo_3 import foo_4,)
                              .foo_5 import foo_6)
```

Comment: The last one looks fine. 
I'd recommend using a formatter like `black` and leave the formatting to it.

Comment: If you import `foo`, `foo.foo_3` and hypothetical `foo.bar4`, you should consider them **separate modules** even if they belong to same package. Thus, you are not repeating yourself. Here's a natural language allegory: is it right or wrong to repeat `Burlington` in a list like `Burlington Public Library, Burlington High School, Burlington Car Wash`? Good namespaces are good. If namespace are excessive in a given package, open a pull request :)